# Command Blocks vs Bukkit Plugin, Performance?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bukkit, performance

I am currently building an open world minecraft adventure map, primarily focused around compatibility for public multiplayer minecraft server. I would like to create events such as; spawning mobs when players enter dungeons, teleporting players between towns and spawning building through the filling and deletion of blocks.

My question is, would it be better to use command blocks and redstone or a custom bukkit plugin written specifically for my purposes. I'm specifically looking for information on lag cause due to filling and deleting block and what kind of performance increase i can get from using one of these methods over the other.

I would also appreciate any other information for the pros and cons of command blocks vs bukkit plugins.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how complex the system would be and what you want to do with it besides put it on the server. I'll leave you with a pro/con comparison between the two.

---

**Command Block**

Pros:

- Easier to create
- Anyone can use the map, not just you
- Don't have to be updated when major changes to the game are done

Cons:

- Redstone circuitry is laggy
- Circuitry can take up lots of space
- Still complex syntax, even though it is easier

---

**Bukkit Plugin**

Pros:

- Map is limited to the server, so it can't be stolen using a mod
- Less laggy
- Takes up no space

Cons:

- Can't distribute the map without it being limited to Bukkit servers
- Hard to code
- If you can't code, developers are expensive

Comment: Command blocks totally have to be updated -- 1.13 completely changed the command system